# use ascx control in a div tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Created a user control named "Uctest.ascx". I want to show this .ascx control in a div tag with out using aspx page. If it's possible means please help me to do this?

Comment: You need aspx page. Have an aspx page with div and control inside it to achieve it.

Comment: hmm, how do you see this?  Where the DIV element is located in this case?

Comment: u cannot put an asp custom control without an aspx page or outside a `form` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people say here it's impossible without aspx page.
However, I can think about a not so clean solution for this.

You can create aspx page, place your control there and load that aspx page through AJAX into your div. But you will lose all server side functionality of this control so I don't know if this solution is any good for you

Comment: Here's how to do it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx

Comment: cant understand how this is the answer of this qstn.. :/

Comment: @Avishek - I don't know if it fits the business requirements of the OP, but it certainly is viable technically. Everyone is correct that an ASCX can't be rendered without a page container, but the container can be executed transparently.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show this .ascx control in a div tag with out using aspx
>   page

You can't.

From [ASP.NET User Controls Overview MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> **User controls cannot run as stand-alone files. Instead, you must add them to ASP.NET pages**, as you would any control.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible.. since a Web User Control has events in its code-behind and those need to be executed, ie who will call the load_event ??

What you can do however...
Is create an IFrame.. and load aspx page into it, which serves as container to your ascx..

Comment: it that case also, he has to put it in a aspx page that will get loaded in the iFrame

Comment: yes, agreed. I just thought that it is more elegant to mention the Iframe there as it should give it the same boxing behavior exepected of a sub-component in a page.